# How to call variable from properties file in shell scripting bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

This is my file (xyz.properties)

```
abcd.123=localhost:8180
```

Now I need this IP address in my shell script

```
vi create.sh
#!/bin/bash
```

How do I call `abcd.123` from properties file to this shell script

## !bin/bash

source = /xyz.properties

${abcd_123}

${"abcd_123"}

${abcd.123}

nothing works

this way is not working and my main idea is to use the variable everywhere
BTW i cannot use abcd_123 in my properties file
as there are so many dependencies on that variable

Comment: You don't; you use a language that has (or in which you can write) a proper parser for this input.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the dots and source the modified content:

```
$ source <(sed 's@\(.*\)\.\(.*\)=@\1_\2=@' xyz.properties)
$ echo $abcd_123
localhost:8180
```

Comment: Hi I didn't understood what you said

Comment: kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1/config/server.properties --- is the location where zookeeper.connect=localhost:80 was stored

Comment: Now I want to use that ip address in myshell.sh file how to do that

Answer (score 0):

in your bash script you need to "source" your properties file (you can use the "source" or "." [a dot]):

```
#!/bin/bash
source yourfile.properties
```

Edited. Change your names to use an underscore instead, then access them like so:

```
${"abcd_123"}
```

Comment: `name`:
A word consisting solely of letters, numbers, and underscores, and beginning with a letter or underscore. Names are used as shell variable and function names. Also referred to as an identifier.

Comment: Indeed, see my comments - unsure what shell OP is using...!

Comment: in fact, OP mentions bash in the title, so my bad there. 

OP: remove the dot, and source the file as mentioned, you access your variables in the same fashion.

Comment: I did as you said,but not working

Comment: in server.properties                                        zookeeper.connect=172.30.0.243:2181

Comment: #!/bin/bash
source=  ~/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1/config/server.properties
echo ${"zookeeper.connect"}

Comment: /home/ec2-user/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1/config/server.properties: line 117: zookeeper.connect=172.30.0.243:2181: command not found
/home/ec2-user/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1/config/server.properties: line 120: zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000: command not found
./create_topic.sh: line 3: ${"zookeeper.connect"}: bad substitution

Comment: if you're in bash land, remove the dots from your names. maybe change properties file to be:
    zookeeper_connect=1.2.3.4

and read like:

    ${zookeeper_connect}